# How do I group multiple output bundles into subdirectories in Vite/Rollup?

Tags: bundle, vite, rollup

I'm working on a svelte project which, in turn, uses vite. However, I need to configure multiple inputs and output directories, for some non-svelte-related stuff — I figured I may as well leverage the existing bundler, rather than set up a whole new project.

I know that I can specify a build path as part of each input key, but this only seems to apply to javascript files, and I want *all* related bundle files to use the path. CSS files are currently output to the dist root, which is not ideal. The relevant part of my vite.config.js looks like this:

```
build: {
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
        input: {
            'svelte/bundle': './src/main.js',
            'admin/bundle': './admin/index.js'
        },
        output: {
            dir: '../../dist',
            entryFileNames: '[name].js',
            assetFileNames: '[name][extname]'
        },
    },
},
plugins: [svelte()]
```

I would like my output to look like the following:

```
dist/
├─ svelte/
│  ├─ bundle.js
│  └─ styles.css
└─ admin/
   ├─ bundle.js
   └─ styles.css
```

But what I currently get is:

```
dist/
├─ svelte/
│  └─ bundle.js
├─ admin/
│  └─ bundle.js
├─ index.css
└─ main.css
```

How do I make sure all CSS files are also included in their respective subdirectories?